# Django: Can I do work after the response has been returned?

Tags: django, request

I have a SLO to return responses from my django app in 3 seconds, but occasionally the work that I'm doing within a request takes longer than this. The extra work can be done asynchronously, so I'm looking into celery.

BUT, the work logically belongs *with* the request and it would be nice if I didn't have to go to all the extra work of setting up a celery queue. I don't have much traffic and I don't mind taking up just a little more time with my uwsgi worker.

Is there any condoned way (or perhaps even un-condoned way) to do work *after* the response has been returned but before leaving the request cycle?

Comment: Can't you use `request_finished` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#request-finished) ?

Comment: @Lotram thanks for the lead! That look like what I want - I can just make callbacks and subscribe them to the request_finished like so 

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
     import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
request_finished.connect(my_callback)
```

Unfortunately, thought, I haven't figured out how to hit the debug point :/ Any extra setup required to get this working?

Comment: @Lotram I got signal working, but it won't be of much use for my current application because I have to subscribe outside of the request cycle so the hook knows nothing of what I want to in a given request. :-(  Thanks though!